# How to create content for child pages of a template?

Tags: objectscript, intersystems-cache-zen

I created a Zen page with a header.  All is good.  I then created a new Zen page and during the wizard specified that it was a "subclass of a template page".  So now I have `Class Custom.App.HomePage Extends Custom.App.TemplateMaster`.  If I visit `HomePage.cls` I see the header from the template.  However, the HomePage class has no `XData Contents` section so I have no idea how to actually add content.  I tried adding the section but once I do then I don't see the template content anymore.

So, how do I put content in a page that extends another page as a template?

The [only documentation I found about templates](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GZEN_layout#GZEN_template_page) doesn't really help and unfortunately I don't have access to the sample files mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using **pane**'s. You can create differents **XData** with the identifier that you want, and add a pane object using the **paneName**. This is a simple example:

```
   Class Custom.App.TemplateMaster
    {
        XData Contents
        {
            <page  xmlns="http://www.intersystems.com/zen" >
                ...
                <pane paneName="HomePageContent" width="100%" />        
                ...
            </page>     
        }
    }




    Class Custom.App.HomePage Extends Custom.App.TemplateMaster
    {
        XData HomePageContent
        {   
            <!-- the specific content of your HomePage ->   
        }
    }
```